# How to handle pagination in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

I am looking to add pagination with htaccess I have htaccess file which rewrites my PHP URLs like mysite/category/programming. but when I click on next page with pagination, the url looks like

`mysite/category.php?category=programming&page=2`

but I want to add pagination like this `mysite/category/programming/page/1`

I need clean URL like below

`mysite/category/programming/page/1`

with

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

but the result is

> mysite/category.php?category=programming&page=2

Comment: In future, you should look into routing all requests through a singular file (like index.php). You shouldn't have to use .htaccess to support pagination but it's a great place to start I guess (e.g `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`)

Comment: _“but I want to add pagination like this mysite/category/programming/page/1”_ - well then teach your system that creates those pagination _links_, that outputs the actual HTML code that contains those URLs, that it should output them in that format, and not the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/page/(.+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ article.php?url=$1
```